# WebEx recording already in MP4 format and not playing

Tags: webex, cisco-webex

I have a recording of a PhD defense I hosted in .MP4 format already available in one of my folders on my Windows system. But when I try to play it, it says - video can't be played. It's a very important file and I don't want to lose it. What do I do?

Comment: Try to play it using [SMPlayer](https://www.smplayer.info/) or [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html).  This will probably tell you if it is a problem with the codec or what.  Both of those players have most codecs built in.  I don't like VLC much but it also seems to play imperfect files.  If it won't play, let me know.

Comment: No, it doesn't play.

Comment: Will VLC give you info for the file?  See if it even has a header? Whatever file you are looking at is probably hosed.. or not a video file at all.  You can use a [hex editor](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) to look at the file to see what is really inside of it. [Here](https://www.file-recovery.com/mp4-signature-format.htm) is a page that will tell you how to look at the header with a hex editor.  Video files ARE rocket science, looking at a header of one isn't ;)